# Docker. How to run a flask server main file that start the server inside deeper file structure

Tags: python, docker, flask, docker-compose

My flask app, the main file that starts the flask server on port 5000 is inside:

Server`/main/core/setup.py`

The Docker gives me this error and I know because it cannot find the `setup.py`:

```
ERROR: for flask_api  Cannot start service flask_api: oci runtime error: 
container_linux.go:265: starting container process caused "exec: 
\"/main/api/core\": stat /main/api/core: no such file or directory"
```

My error is inside the Dockerfile:

I change my default path of the `setup.py` from the `Server/setup.py` to `Server/app/main/core/setup.py`

Question how to start the server on this path

### Dockerfile:

#### This is before I move the setup.py file that starts the server on port 5000

```
# FROM python:3.6-alpine
# ADD ./Server /app
# WORKDIR /app
# RUN pip install -r requirements.txt
# EXPOSE 5000
# CMD ["python", "api.py"]
```

#### This is after I move the file deeper

```
FROM python:3.6-alpine
ADD ./Server /app
WORKDIR /app
RUN pip install -r requirements.txt
EXPOSE 5000
ENTRYPOINT ["/main/core"]
CMD ["python", "setup.py"]
```

### Any help how to hit the setup.py ??

Comment: Your `ENTRYPOINT` line does not make any sense like that.

Comment: I just notice that is for exe files

Comment: i just organize my server code and i remove the setup file from the root of the folder and i moved 2 levels deaper . What i can to to run the setup.py 2 levels deaper

Answer (score 3, accepted):

There is a little mess with entrypoint (https://docs.docker.com/engine/reference/builder/#entrypoint) and workdir (https://docs.docker.com/engine/reference/builder/#workdir)
Please remember that you can use WORKDIR multiple times.

Your setup.py should be in path:

```
Server/main/core/setup.py
```

I suppose that your Dockerfile should be:

```
FROM python:3.6-alpine
ADD ./Server /app
WORKDIR /app 
RUN pip install -r requirements.txt
EXPOSE 5000
WORKDIR /app/main/core
CMD ["python", "setup.py"]
```

Comment: Thanks, Bro this help me. I am sorry I am new to Docker